# Changing minimum height of a content div to match 2 others dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, height

Alright, so I have a page with 3 divs set up within a wrapper like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper" style="width:608px;">

<div id="leftcolumn" style="float: left; border:2px solid #000000; width: 300px;">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
</div>

<div id="rightcolumn" style="float: right; border:2px solid #000000; width: 300px;">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
</div>

<div id="lefboottomtcolumn" style="clear: left; float: left; border:2px solid #000000; width: 300px;">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
</div>

</div>

</body>
```

Now, all 3 divs are free to expand with their varying content, however I would very much like it if - in the event the right column's content if very minimal and is therefore smaller than the 2 left columns combined - the right columns's height or minimum height (whichever is more appropriate) could adjust to match the other columns but still retain to ability to expand beyond that point whenever the content calls for it. And it should be noted that if the right column is tallest of the bunch, the others DON'T adjust to it, those always remain the same.

Changing the minimum height of the right column dynamically using javascript is probably the way to go, but I have no experience coding stuff like that. I've seen plenty of script to make columns even, but that not's quite the result I'm looking for here obviously. I tried adapting these scripts to my needs to no avail... I'm not sure how to get the total height of both left columns (which also has a 10px margin inbetween).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a CSS way to sort this out but that would require you to alter your HTML.

I would go with a simple jQuery solution such as the below:

```
<title></title>
</head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

<div id="wrapper" style="width:608px;">

<div id="leftcolumn" style="float: left; border:2px solid #000000; width: 300px;">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
</div>

<div id="rightcolumn" style="float: right; border:2px solid #000000; width: 300px;">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
</div>

<div id="lefboottomtcolumn" style="clear: left; float: left; border:2px solid #000000; width: 300px;">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
</div>

</div>
<script>
var totalHeightLeft = $('#leftcolumn').height() + $('#lefboottomtcolumn').height() + 4 //for the borders

$('#rightcolumn').css('min-height',totalHeightLeft + 'px')
</script>
</body>
```

Essentially it's grabbing the height of the 2 left elements and it corrects for the additional 4px (between the 2 left elements) of border and then sets the mininum height on the righter element. This solution most likely won't work in IE7 as the min-height property is not used in IE7 I believe.

Comment: If you had to do it with CSS like you first mentioned, how would it be done? If it's simpler than using javascript/jQuery and it doesn't change the layout then I might just use that instead.

Comment: Looking back at what you are trying to achieve it looks like javascript might be the only way to do this. In order for the browser to know what height to set the rightColumn div to, it needs to be able to get this height from somewhere, in this case the parent element (div wrapper). Since the wrapper has no pre-defined height but depends on the content in the left columns it won't be able to inherit from the wrapper and will therefore get a height that matches the content in the rightColumn. Unless you set a fixed height on the wrapper, javascript is your only option.

Comment: Yes, it seems it could only be solved using javascript. Following the logic of the jQuery script you gave me I was able to devise a simple script (I'm just more accumstomed to regular javascript) that did pretty much what I wanted.